# How to trigger onClick() function inside ES6 function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried to trigger `onClick()` function inside ES6 function but not doing at all.

HTML

```
<a onclick="call()">Call</a>
```

JS

```
voximplant.on(VoxImplant.Events.IncomingCall, (e) => {
    function call(){ //I want to trigger this one
        e.call.answer(videoFlags);
    }
}
```

PS: the html page will show up if `voximplant.on(VoxImplant.Events.IncomingCall` occured.

Comment: What do you want the `e` to be when `call` is called? Will a single `voximplant.on(VoxImplant.Events.IncomingCall` already have occurred, or something?

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `IncomingCall` handler fires, attach another event handler to your `a` to call the `call` function:

```
voximplant.on(VoxImplant.Events.IncomingCall, (e) => {
    document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
        e.call.answer(videoFlags);
    });
}
```

It sounds like you may want the `e.call.answer` to occur only once, in which case use `{ once: true }` as a third argument to `addEventListener` so the `a` click listener only fires once.

Comment: if there will be 3 onClick()s, how to identify each of it?

Comment: What would you want to happen when there are 3 clicks? The first click would result in the prior `IncomingCall` event being used, but what would a second or third click mean? If you want to call the same `e.call.answer` again on subsequent clicks, then just use the code above (without `{ once: true }`)

Comment: because there will be call(), decline() and hangup(). how to differentiate using querySelector()?

Comment: `querySelector` accepts a selector string. Hard to say without being able to see the HTML, but you just pass the selector string that matches the element you want to attach the listener to. Eg if the `call` `<a>` has a class of `call`, use `document.querySelector('a.call')`. If the decline `<a>` has a class of `decline`, use `document.querySelector('a.decline')`, etc